# Datadog Terraform (IaC) - directory layout strategy with multiple organizations

Tags: automation, terraform, monitoring, datadog

I'm trying to import my whole Datadog environment to the Terraform configuration. My account has access to multiple organizations. I want to import it to the single Monolithics repository. 
Unfortunately, I met the issue with directory layout startegy - I'm not sure how it should look based on **Terraform best practices**.

**I suggested:**

```
datadog-iac-repo:
    organizations/
       org1/
         user/
         monitors/
         dashboards/
       org2/
         user/
         monitors/
         dashboards/
       org3/
         user/
         monitors/
         dashboards/
    tools/
    init.tf
    main.tf
```

or

```
datadog-iac-repo:
    user/
       org1/
       org2/
       org3/
    dashboards/
       org1/
       org2/
       org3/
    monitors/
       org1/
       org2/
       org3/
    tools/
    init.tf
    main.tf
```

Does somebody have experience with the issue? What do you think? 
Could you provide me your experience?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I had something similar issue and chose the first option, but i won't say it is from terraform perspective (since i also had lack in experience in terraform). 
The first hierarchy was more reasonable in segregation aspects, plus would be easier to add/remove/update organizations by demand.

Comment: Did you created the module for resource like user/dashbaord etc?

Comment: yes, similar to yours just with monitors and dashboards

Comment: Could you share your directory strategy?